# Android fragments re-use with BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have application with main content that is composed of 1 of 3  `Fragments` and `BottomNavigationView` that has 3 options. Each button on the `BottomNavigationView` switches main content with one of the 3 `Fragments`.

In methods for switching `Fragments` I find if the `Fragment` already exists by a tag. If it does I do not create new instance but use the existing instance:

```
    private void switchToDailyFragment(int fragmentArgument) {

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment dailyFragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(String.valueOf(TrainingFragment.MODE_DAY));

    if (dailyFragment == null) {
        dailyFragment = TrainingFragment.newInstance(fragmentArgument);
        Log.d(TAG, "switchToDailyFragment: no instance of monthly fragment, making instance now");
    }

    manager.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
            .replace(R.id.main_content, dailyFragment, String.valueOf(TrainingFragment.MODE_DAY))
            .commit();

}
```

I set up static counter variable that increments everytime the factory method `newInstance(int mode)` of my `Fragment` is called:

```
  public static int instanceCount = 0;
```

and increment it like this:

```
    public static TrainingFragment newInstance(int mode) {
    instanceCount++;
    Log.d(TAG, "newInstance: instace count: " + instanceCount);
    TrainingFragment fragment = new TrainingFragment();
    fragment.setMode(mode);
    return fragment;
}
```

So I thought the way it is set up, it should create at most 3 instances of my `Fragment` for each button in `BottomNavigationView` and then reuse these instances. 
But more instances are created everytime item is selected even after there already are 3 instances according to the logs:

```
 D/TrainingFragment: newInstance: instace count: 1
 D/TrainingFragment: newInstance: instace count: 2
 D/TrainingFragment: newInstance: instace count: 3
 D/TrainingFragment: newInstance: instace count: 4
 D/TrainingFragment: newInstance: instace count: 5
 D/TrainingFragment: newInstance: instace count: 6
 D/TrainingFragment: newInstance: instace count: 7
 D/TrainingFragment: newInstance: instace count: 8
 and so on
```

Is this the normal behavior or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: TrainingFragment.MODE_DAY what is this value ?

Comment: its int of value 0 - I have three modes for my TrainingFragment - either 0, 1 or 2